# Angular: afterCellEdit without scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'm trying to implement the afterCellEdit function inside my gridOption.onREgisterApi function. I'm not using $scope in my program as is recommended to do in the guidelines.

In fact, my question is exactly the same as this one : [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29114156/can-angular-ui-grid-edit-be-used-with-controller-as-syntax)
Sadly it is not answered.
When I use null as one of the answer suggest I got an error.

Here is the code :

```
  vm.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function(gridApi){
    vm.gridApi = gridApi;
    vm.gridApi.edit.on.afterCellEdit(null,function(rowEntity, colDef, newValue, oldValue){
      alert("afterCellEdit");
    });
  };
```

And here is my error :

```
typeError: Cannot read property '$on' of null
at Object.feature.on.(anonymous function) [as afterCellEdit]
```

Thanks !

Edit : for @SaurabhTiwari here is my $scope.gridData alternative

```
function onCustomerListComplete(data) {
    vm.gridOptions.data = data;
}


function OnError(reason) {
    $log.error(reason);
}

function activate() {
  customerService.getCustomerList()
            .then(onCustomerListComplete, OnError);
}

vm.gridOptions = { 
    enablePaginationControls: false,
    useExternalSorting: true,
    enableHorizontalScrollbar : uiGridConstants.scrollbars.NEVER,
    enableVerticalScrollbar : uiGridConstants.scrollbars.WHEN_NEEDED,
  columnDefs: [
  // will be modified once the data model is set
    { field: 'id', name: '', cellTemplate: 'content/customerList/rowEditor/customerList.rowEditor.editButton.html', width: 34 },
    { name: 'customerNumber', },
    { name: 'customerName' },
    { name: 'city' },
    { name: 'creditLimit' },
    { name: 'postalCode' },
  ]
};
```

Comment: I am not sure which guidelines are you referring to. But in my opinion `$scope` is required here to `watch` a change on your `editBox`. Same can be deciphered from the error you are receiving, as `$on` can't work without `$scope`

Comment: @SaurabhTiwari The one by Angular's developer John papa : https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide

Comment: In that case where are you binding your data. What's your alternative for `$scope.gridData = {data: dataList}`. I doubt vm.gridData wouldn't work in this case.

Comment: It does. I didn't add it in my question because it works and cause no problems. I'll add it as an edit.

Comment: Thanks for your update. I see now how it works, however if its a `$on` listener it would be fired only on `$scope`. Will try to get back if I found a way around

Comment: @SaurabhTiwari Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

It might be late to provide some help here and you possibly have found a solution. But I would like to explain your condition using the below code.

```
function (scope, handler, _this) {
            if ( scope !== null && typeof(scope.$on) === 'undefined' ){
              gridUtil.logError('asked to listen on ' + featureName + '.on.' + eventName + ' but scope wasn\'t passed in the input parameters.  It is legitimate to pass null, but you\'ve passed something else, so you probably forgot to provide scope rather than did it deliberately, not registering');
              return;
            }
            var deregAngularOn = registerEventWithAngular(eventId, handler, self.grid, _this);

            //track our listener so we can turn off and on
            var listener = {handler: handler, dereg: deregAngularOn, eventId: eventId, scope: scope, _this:_this};
            self.listeners.push(listener);

            var removeListener = function(){
              listener.dereg();
              var index = self.listeners.indexOf(listener);
              self.listeners.splice(index,1);
            };

            //destroy tracking when scope is destroyed
            if (scope) {
              scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
                removeListener();
              });
            }


            return removeListener;
          }
```

This is the original code from the ui-grid Api. You can search for it in the library or from a proper scope in application you can just try doing:
`$scope.gridApi.edit.on.afterCellEdit.toString()`

So the point here is that this function explicitly requires a scope or a null. So You do need to pass a scope to this listener.

The point you mentioned in your question that you are not using `$scope` in your code is somewhat vague. There always is a `scope` associated if you have a controller. Angular is pretty much about `scopes` (atleast Angular 1 was).

What the referred guidelines says is that you should avoid heaping everything on your `$scope`. The guidelines also says you should use `$scope` only for listening and watching, which is exactly the case here